# Pass parameter inside $location.path in angular

Tags: angularjs

im just tryin to pass a parametr into location.path,

```
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../controller/subscriber.php',
            data: $scope.data, 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          })
            .success(function (data) {
                if (data.error === "false") {
                 $location.path("/group/detail/$routeParams.gId");
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add Parameters you should use this

```
 $location.path("/group/detail/"+$routeParams.gId);
```

Answer (score 2):

to add Parameters you should use $location.search() method so:

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

`$location` methods are chainable.

this produce :

```
/myURL/?param=value
```